# linux append path to secure_path for running pyenv with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, path, sudo, pyenv

I have installed [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), but when I run `sudo pip install xx`

```
sudo: pip: command not found
```

I know that append `/app/pyenv/shims:/app/pyenv/bin`(my `PYENV_ROOT='/app/pyenv'`) to `secure_path` and use

```
Defaults secure_path += /app/pyenv/shims
```

in `/etc/sudoers.d/pyenv`,but failed with

```
/usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory
```

The output of `echo 'echo $PATH' | sudo /bin/bash`

```
/app/pyenv/shims
```

shows that secure_path just be overwritten.

so how can I append path on the original basis of secure_path in the best way?

Comment: What is the OS you are running this in?

Comment: @RamanSailopal   mostly `centos6.5 x64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that have no way to add `new_path` on `original secure_path` like `Defaults secure_path += /app/pyenv/shims`, but there are others way to solve it, without change `secure_path` now:

1. `sudo -i cmd`, it will execute the user's profile,ref from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8695 (***best***)

   ```
   echo 'echo $PATH' | sudo -i /bin/bash
   /app/pyenv/shims:/app/pyenv/bin:/app/pyenv/shims:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/root/bin
   ```
2. add `Defaults exempt_group=user1` ,ref from [exempt_group](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.19/sudoers.man.html) and [The exempt_group option in sudo](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/150783)

   > exempt_group
   >   Users in this group are exempt from password and PATH requirements. The group name specified should not include a % prefix. This is not set by default.

BTW: any know any way to add `new_path` on `original secure_path` like `Defaults secure_path += /app/pyenv/shims` and post it will be appreciated!